# Terraform Does not BIND a local directory to container's file system

Tags: jenkins, terraform, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I am setting up a 3 node Docker Swarm based infrastructure to spin Jenkins instances for various projects within my org. I have a terraform module that creates a docker service using the terraform.tfvars file which contains the instance name, port number, docker image name etc.

Under normal circumstances, this works fine for me. But my challenge is that over time, if the jenkins service is started in a different worker node, it will lose contents already created. To over come this, I created an NFS mount named, /jenkins which is shared across the docker swarm nodes.

Problem:

When I try to bind the container's "/var/jenkins_home" to "/jenkins/" it doesn't work for me. When I run docker service command manually, it creates the local file binding without issues.

PS:I've already overcome the user ID issue raised here, https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md by making a custom version of the docker image with user ID matching the hosts's jenkins user

```
#This is the main script used by the project

resource "docker_service" "jenkins_service" {
  name = var.project_name
  task_spec {
    container_spec {
      image = docker_image.jenkins_image.name
      mounts {
        source = var.jenkins_volume
        target = "/var/jenkins_name"
        type   = "volume"
      }
      mounts {
        source = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        target = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        type   = "bind"
      }
    }
    networks = ["${docker_network.jenkins_network.name}"]
  }

  endpoint_spec {
    ports {
      target_port    = "8080"
      published_port = var.web_interface_port
      publish_mode   = "ingress"
      name           = "WEB_INTERFACE"
    }
    ports {
      target_port    = "50000"
      published_port = var.api_interface_port
      publish_mode   = "ingress"
      name           = "API_INTERFACE"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Result: The code should (1) create a docker service, (2) Spawn a docker container (3) Map the container's /var/jenkins_home to /jenkins/ on host

Observed Result:
The code (1) creates a docker service, (2) Spawns a docker container (3) Created a virtual docker volume instead of binding to local file system

Answer (score 0):

Its either StackOverflow ju je or some fresh perspective. The issue was a typo in mount definition.

The code had jenkins_name instead of jenkins_home. This is resolved now